# how main div to be appeared in center in IE?

Tags: html, css

I have one issue,I created a main div and used center tag to make it appear in center of page and it working fine in Firefox but in IE it appears in left side even after use of center tag,I also tried margin = auto. Please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

`margin: 0 auto;` is the best way to accomplish this.

The element **cannot** have a `float:;`.

The element **cannot** be displayed as an `inline-block` or `inline` element.

The element **must** be displayed as a `block` element *and* have a defined width.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
whee, i'm a centered div!
</div>
```

---

**Your entire page code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page Title</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                display: block;
                width: 960px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            whee, i'm a centered div!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It also must have an explicit width.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I already used above code,But it is not working,so if you have any other solution please reply.

Comment: @user952044 the above code should work, revise your code. Here an online example http://jsfiddle.net/karameloso/Hk4vd/

Comment: I don't think this guy knows how to reference CSS in his files. Answer revised.

Comment: Ironically, the "Your entire page code" won't actually be centered in Internet Explorer. You forgot the doctype :)

Comment: ^ Thanks. I seem to forget the easy things when it's early in the morning/late into the late :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="centered">Hello again, World!</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
#centered { 
  width: 500px; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -250px; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,yes your solution works but this is not the fixed solution of this problem,let me know if you have some appropriate solution for this.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks eh, No `<center>` tag here?

Comment: Ah damn, I read that wring, make an edit and I'll remove my downvote, terribly sorry there.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `DOCTYPE` is included very top of every web page in your Document. `DOCTYPE's` are a key component of compliant web pages: your markup and `CSS` won’t validate without them.